# Why can't I update author field in SharePoint online using pnp powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, spfield

I have tried to update the Author field in a library or file in `SharePoint online`, and it throws an error, like it Author field is read only. Yes, I know what read-only means, but why this difference with the on-premise? Setting other fields like Editor,etc, works fine.

Is there a way to change the author field for Folders and Files?

```
 $values = @{
                    Author = $item.Author;
                }

                $file = Get-PnPFile -Url 

                # Update the property
                Set-PnPListItem -List "Library1" -Identity $file.Id -Values $values
```

---

```
    Name                        Version
    ----                        -------
    
    SharePointPnPPowerShell2019 3.29.2101.0
```

---

```
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      7.4.0
    PSEdition                      Core
    GitCommitId                    7.4.0
    Platform                       Win32NT
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I have tried to use CSOM directly, but I can't access it as in our environment
we use form authentication which prevents me from logging. I don't know how to set it here in CSOM, but with PnP -UseWebLogin I can access the site.
Is there a way to specify the authentication method is web form while using CSOM, just like they do with PnP?

```
 #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
       
    $SiteUrl = "https://site1.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/"
    $ListName= "Projects"
     
    $Cred = Get-Credential
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
     
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

The Author field in SharePoint Online is read-only and cannot be updated directly.

You can try using the PnP.PowerShell cmdlet `Set-PnPListItem`, ex.

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Identity "4" -Values @{"Author"= "2019/15/04 12:15:00 AM"}
```

In terms of authentication with CSOM, if you’re doing forms or claims-based authentication, you’ll have to tell your context

```
$ctx.AuthenticationMode = "FormsAuthentication"
$ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("domainusername", "password")
```

Alternatively, you can use the GetWebLoginClientContext method of SharePoint PnP Core library which is available as a NuGet package.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707476/authentication-to-sharepoint-online-with-csom

Ref: https://mstechtalk.com/update-created-created-by-modified-modified-fields-using-sharepoint-online-powershell/